# i cannot properly link boost.JSON to my project using CMake

Tags: c++, json, cmake

Tree level overview of my project:

```
├── build
│   ├── build.ninja
│   ├── CMakeCache.txt
│   ├── CMakeFiles
│   │   ├── 3.18.0-rc1
│   │   ├── cmake.check_cache
│   │   ├── CMakeError.log
│   │   ├── CMakeOutput.log
│   │   ├── CMakeTmp
│   │   ├── cmake.verify_globs
│   │   ├── hftbot.dir
│   │   ├── Makefile2
│   │   ├── progress.marks
│   │   ├── rules.ninja
│   │   ├── TargetDirectories.txt
│   │   └── VerifyGlobs.cmake
│   ├── cmake_install.cmake
│   ├── compile_commands.json
│   ├── details.json
│   ├── external
│   │   └── json
│   ├── hftbot
│   ├── Makefile
│   └── src
│       ├── CMakeFiles
│       ├── cmake_install.cmake
│       └── Makefile
├── build.sh
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── configure.sh
├── details.json
├── external
│   ├── asio
│   │   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   │   ├── doc
│   │   ├── example
│   │   ├── include
│   │   ├── index.html
│   │   ├── meta
│   │   ├── test
│   │   └── tools
│   ├── CMakeLists.txt
│   └── json
│       ├── bench
│       ├── build
│       ├── CHANGELOG.md
│       ├── check
│       ├── cmake
│       ├── CMakeLists.txt
│       ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
│       ├── doc
│       ├── example
│       ├── fuzzing
│       ├── include
│       ├── index.html
│       ├── Jamfile
│       ├── LICENSE_1_0.txt
│       ├── meta
│       ├── README.md
│       ├── src
│       └── test
├── run.sh
└── src
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── httpClient.cpp
    └── WebsocketClient.cpp
```

https://github.com/boostorg/json
i cloned this project to "external/json" directory from root directory.

I added following commands in CMakeLists.txt in the root directory

```
target_include_directories(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC "external/json/include")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PUBLIC boost_json)
```

And when i add this :

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <boost/json/src.hpp>
```

it says that source boost/json.hpp and boost/json/src.hpp is not found.

Comment: Please show a [mre]